# How to put text or boxes of text above the back address in scrlttr2

Tags: header-footer, letters, scrlttr2

I want to put 5 boxes of text above the back address line. For that matter I set `firsthead` to `false`. The text size can be the same size as the back address text size. The maximal length of each box will be 25 characters. In the picture I marked the text with red for better explanation. And if it is not too difficult how is it possible to put the page number at that weird location.

Edit: After some searching I found `textpos` and came up with the following solution. The boxes overlap each other and I get warnings because I use tabulars. But I have no other solution how to allign the damn numbers without using them. Also I have to find another place for the last box, since it does not fit.

Here is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, version=last, fromalign=left, backaddress=true, foldmarks=on, fromphone=off, fromemail=on, parskip=half, firsthead=false]{scrlttr2} 
% 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{lmodern}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}      
\usepackage[absolute,overlay, quiet]{textpos}         
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}   

\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}  % Signatur wird bündig gesetzt


\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
%
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
% Absender
% 
\newcommand{\mVorname}{ tlexxier kinorelekt GmbH} 
\newcommand{\mNachname}{\& Co. KG} 
\newcommand{\mStrasse}{Somestr. 1} 
\newcommand{\mStadt}{Stadt} 
\newcommand{\mPLZ}{23332} 
\setkomavar{date}{} 

\setkomavar{fromname}{\mVorname{}~\mNachname{}}               % Name 
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{\mStrasse{}\\{}\mPLZ{}~\mStadt{}}    % Adresse

\makeatletter
\@setplength{locvpos}{5.8cm}
\@setplength{locwidth}{6cm}
\makeatother
\begin{document} 

%recipient  
\begin{letter}{%    
Max Musterkunde \\
Teststraße 2    \\
55555 Teststadt \\
Schweiz         \\ 
     }
     
\setkomavar{location}{\raggedright 
Versandanschrift:\\
Muxiline Wirrewar Institute \\
Sagblobbberavenue 8323  \\
23423 Blablubbing       \\
Blabistan
} 
% 
%\setkomavar{title}{Titel} 
\setkomavar{subject}{Rechnung} 
% 
\opening{} 
%
test test test
% 

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north east,yshift=-20.0pt,xshift=-10]%
        at (current page.north east)
        {\includegraphics[height=18mm, width=95mm]{example-image-b}};
    \node [anchor=north west,yshift=-20.0pt,xshift=47]%
        at (current page.north west)
        {\includegraphics[height=15mm, width=35mm]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}


    \begin{textblock*}{4cm}(1.7cm,2.8cm) % {block width} (coords) 
    \footnotesize 
    \begin{tabular}{l@{\hskip3pt}l}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{firstcontact:} \\
              Tel.   & +41 (0)1111 333-444  \\
              Fax    & +41 (0)2222 666-555  \\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{www.somewebsite.ch}      
    \end{tabular}
    \end{textblock*}

    \begin{textblock*}{4cm}(6cm,2.8cm) % {block width} (coords) 
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}{l@{\hskip3pt}l}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{secondcontact:} \\
              Tel.   & +41 (0)1111 333-444  \\
              Fax    & +41 (0)2222 666-555  \\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{www.someotherwebsite.ch}      
    \end{tabular}
    \end{textblock*}

    \begin{textblock*}{4cm}(10.3cm,2.8cm) % {block width} (coords) 
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}{l@{\hskip3pt}l}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{thirdcontact:} \\
              Tel.   & +41 (0)1111 333-444  \\
              Fax    & +41 (0)2222 666-555  \\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{www.someotherwebsite.ch}      
    \end{tabular}
    \end{textblock*}

    \begin{textblock*}{4cm}(14.6cm,2.8cm) % {block width} (coords) 
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}{l@{\hskip3pt}l}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{lactcontact:} \\
              Tel.   & +41 (0)1111 333-444  \\
              Fax    & +41 (0)2222 666-555  \\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{www.someotherwebsite.ch}      
    \end{tabular}
    \end{textblock*}

\end{letter} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `firsthead` and adjust `firstheadvpos`:

```latex
\setplength{firstheadvpos}{30mm}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}{%
    \parbox{\useplength{firstheadwidth}}{%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\hskip3pt}l}
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{firstcontact:} \\
        Tel.   & +41 (0)1111 333-444  \\
        Fax    & +41 (0)2222 666-555  \\
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{www.somewebsite.ch}
      \end{tabular}%
      \hfill
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{\hskip3pt}l}
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{secondcontact:} \\
        Tel.   & +41 (0)1111 333-444  \\
        Fax    & +41 (0)2222 666-555  \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{www.someotherwebsite.ch}
      \end{tabular}%
      \hfill
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{\hskip3pt}l}
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{thirdcontact:} \\
        Tel.   & +41 (0)1111 333-444  \\
        Fax    & +41 (0)2222 666-555  \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{www.someotherwebsite.ch}
      \end{tabular}%
      \hfill
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{\hskip3pt}l}
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{lastcontact:} \\
        Tel.   & +41 (0)1111 333-444  \\
        Fax    & +41 (0)2222 666-555  \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{www.someotherwebsite.ch}
      \end{tabular}%
      \hfill
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
        someother \\
        stuff\\
        bla\\
        Auto
      \end{tabular}%
}}}

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scriptsize}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt,
  parskip=half,
  firsthead=true% <- changed
]{scrlttr2} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx, xcolor etc.

%\LoadLetterOption{visualize}% loads visualize.lco to visualize boxes
%\showfields{address}% show the address box

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}  % Signatur wird bündig gesetzt

%\usepackage[official]{eurosym}

\newcommand{\mVorname}{ tlexxier kinorelekt GmbH} 
\newcommand{\mNachname}{\& Co. KG} 
\newcommand{\mStrasse}{Somestr. 1} 
\newcommand{\mStadt}{Stadt} 
\newcommand{\mPLZ}{23332} 
\setkomavar{date}{} 

\setkomavar{fromname}{\mVorname{}~\mNachname{}}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{\mStrasse{}\\{}\mPLZ{}~\mStadt{}}

\setplength{locvpos}{5.8cm}
\setplength{locwidth}{6cm}
\setplength{firstheadvpos}{30mm}% <- added
%\setplength{firstheadhpos}{50pt}
%\setplength{firstheadwidth}{\paperwidth}
%\addtoplength{firstheadwidth}{-65pt}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}{%
    \parbox{\useplength{firstheadwidth}}{%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\hskip3pt}l}
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{firstcontact:} \\
        Tel.   & +41 (0)1111 333-444  \\
        Fax    & +41 (0)2222 666-555  \\
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{www.somewebsite.ch}
      \end{tabular}%
      \hfill
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{\hskip3pt}l}
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{secondcontact:} \\
        Tel.   & +41 (0)1111 333-444  \\
        Fax    & +41 (0)2222 666-555  \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{www.someotherwebsite.ch}
      \end{tabular}%
      \hfill
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{\hskip3pt}l}
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{thirdcontact:} \\
        Tel.   & +41 (0)1111 333-444  \\
        Fax    & +41 (0)2222 666-555  \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{www.someotherwebsite.ch}
      \end{tabular}%
      \hfill
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{\hskip3pt}l}
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{lastcontact:} \\
        Tel.   & +41 (0)1111 333-444  \\
        Fax    & +41 (0)2222 666-555  \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{www.someotherwebsite.ch}
      \end{tabular}%
      \hfill
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
        someother \\
        stuff\\
        bla\\
        Auto
      \end{tabular}%
}}}

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scriptsize}

\begin{document} 

\begin{letter}{%    
  Max Musterkunde\\
  Teststraße 2\\
  55555 Teststadt\\
  Schweiz\\ 
}

\setkomavar{location}{\raggedright 
  Versandanschrift:\\
  Muxiline Wirrewar Institute \\
  Sagblobbberavenue 8323\\
  23423 Blablubbing\\
  Blabistan
} 

\setkomavar{subject}{Rechnung} 
\opening{} 
test test test

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north east,yshift=-20.0pt,xshift=-10]%
      at (current page.north east)
      {\includegraphics[height=18mm, width=95mm]{example-image-b}};
    \node [anchor=north west,yshift=-20.0pt,xshift=47]%
      at (current page.north west)
      {\includegraphics[height=15mm, width=35mm]{example-image-a}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have a bad box warnining `head of first page is 8.9208pt too high.` Can I safely ignore it?

Comment: It is a warning regarding the space between the header of the first page and the address field. You have to ensure that the tables do not overlap with the address field. The tables should not be visible in the window of the envelope.