# jinja template engine statement conflicts with {%

Tags: header-footer, warnings, comments, scrlttr2, jinja-template

tldr/solution: The jinja template engine default statement is defined as `{%,%}` and it conflicts with % at the end of the line (which is simply not a comment) in a combination with the parenthesis `{`. The simplest solution is just to redefine the default statement to something else. In the c++ library `{{inja}}` it is the command: `env.set_statement("{~", "~}");` e.g.

With [help](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/612690/227165) I have added boxes between the the address field and the header. Now I am using a `jinja` style template engine to fill the tex file with data. This means that I cannot have any `{%` combination in my tex template. So I have removed any `%` behind a `{` that I could find. But removing it after the `\setkomavar{firsthead}{%` or `\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}{%` lines causes two other bad box warnings. Strangely if I leave an empty lines like that

```
\setkomavar{firsthead}{

  \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}{
  
    \parbox{\useplength{firstheadwidth}}{
```

there is no additional warnings to the one I have in the first place. What would be the solution here? And what is the meaning of a comment like that behind a opening `{`?

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=11pt,
parskip=half,
firstfoot=off
]{scrlttr2}  
%

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{lmodern}  
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage[textwidth=\useplength{firstfootwidth}]{geometry} %showframe
%\usepackage[absolute,overlay,quiet]{textpos} %option: showboxes 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}           
          
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}   
%\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}  % Signatur wird bündig gesetzt 


%--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
% Absender
% 
\newcommand{\mVorname}{iiiiiiii elelelelll GmbH} 
\newcommand{\mNachname}{\& Co. KG} 
\newcommand{\mStrasse}{Ellllllllllllg. 1} 
\newcommand{\mStadt}{Sssss} 
\newcommand{\mPLZ}{00000} 
\setkomavar{date}{\today} 

\setkomavar{fromname}{\mVorname{}~\mNachname{}}               % Name 
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{\mStrasse{}\\{}\mPLZ{}~\mStadt{}}    % Adresse

\setkomavar{location}{\raggedright 
Versandanschrift:\\
\vfill
TOM Tompson \\
Blablablub Str.  \\
01011 Blablubbing       \\ 
Blabistan               \\
Telefon
} 


\setplength{locvpos}{4.75cm} 
\setplength{locheight}{3.5cm} 
\setplength{locwidth}{7.5cm}
\setplength{firstfootvpos}{250mm}
\setplength{firstheadvpos}{30mm}
\setplength{refvpos}{9cm}
\setplength{subjectvpos}{\useplength{refvpos}+1.5cm}

%\LoadLetterOption{visualize}% loads visualize.lco to visualize boxes
%\showfields{head,address,location,refline,foot}% show 

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}{%
    \parbox{\useplength{firstheadwidth}}{
      \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{\hskip3pt}l}
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Xxxxxxxxxxxxxx} \\
        Tel.   & +00 (0)0000 000-000  \\
        Fax    & +00 (0)0000 000-000  \\
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{www.aaaaaaaa.de}
      \end{tabular}%
      \hfill
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{\hskip3pt}l}
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Xxxxxxxxxxx} \\
        Tel.   & +00 (0)0000 000-000 \\
        Fax    & +00 (0)0000 000-000  \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{bbbbbbbbb@aaaaaaaa.de}
      \end{tabular}%
      \hfill
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{\hskip3pt}l}
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Xxxxxxxx} \\
        Tel.   & +00 (0)0000 000-000  \\
        Fax    & +00 (0)0000 000-000  \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{sssssss@aaaaaaaa.de}
      \end{tabular}%
      \hfill
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{\hskip3pt}l}
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{Xxxxxxx} \\
        Tel.   & +00 (0)0000 000-000  \\
        Fax    & +00 (0)0000 000-000  \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{eeeeee@aaaaaaaa.de}
      \end{tabular}%
      \hfill
      {\tiny
      \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
        nnnnnnnn Vvvvvvv \\
        19633\\
        2929299\\
        Aoao
      \end{tabular}%
      }
}}}


%redifine pagemark to show current page of all pages
\renewcommand*\pagemark{
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}{\pagename~\thepage~von~\letterlastpage}%
}

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scriptsize}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% <- sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  textarea,
  voffset=\useplength{firstfootvpos},
  hoffset=\dimexpr.5\paperwidth-.5\useplength{firstfootwidth}\relax,
  width=\useplength{firstfootwidth},
  mode=picture,
  contents=\putUL{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height}{\usekomavar{firstfoot}}}
]{likefirstpage.foot}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{scrheadings}{likefirstpage.foot}
\clearpairofpagestyles

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  page,
  addvoffset=20pt+.3333em,
  addhoffset=47pt+.3333em,
  addwidth=-47pt-.6666em,
  addheight=-20pt-.6666em,
  mode=picture,
  contents={
    \putUR{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height}{\makebox[0pt][r]{\includegraphics[height=18mm]{example-image}\hspace{10pt}}}}% reichelt2.png
    \putUL{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height}{\includegraphics[height=15mm]{example-image}}}%
    \putLR{\makebox[0pt][r]{\includegraphics[height=13mm]{example-image}}}% 
  }
]{logos}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{logos,likefirstpage.foot}% <- add likefirstpage.foot to @everystyle@
%\AtBeginLetter{\flushbottom}

\begin{document} 

%recipient  
\begin{letter}{ 
Max Musterkunde \\
Teststraße 2    \\
55555 Teststadt \\
Schweiz         \\ 
     }


\removereffields %<- delete default order of the predifined variables

\setkomavar{invoice}[Rechnungsnummer]{1234567}
\setkomavar{customer}[Kundennummer]{ABCDEFP}


\newkomavar[Bestellnummer]{ordernr}%<-- custom variables

\setkomavar{ordernr}{9082081895889082}

\addtoreffields{invoice}   %<-- custom order of variables
\addtoreffields{customer} 
\addtoreffields{ordernr}

% 
%\setkomavar{title}{Titel} 
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject} 
% 
\opening{}
%
    


{\footnotesize
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{\hskip0pt}r p{3.1cm} X r r r@{\hskip0pt}}

M & A & B & W & E & G \\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{2}{l}{A} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{A} \\
\multicolumn{2}{l}{B} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{B} \\ \\
M & A & B & W & E & G  \\ \hline 
\endhead



\hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Bla}
\endlastfoot
One & abcdef & ghjijklmn & 123.456778 & 5 & 6\\ *[\fill]
\end{xltabular}
}
%\blindtext[10]


\end{letter} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I second the comment about escaping combinations like `{%` and `{{`. Even if you could avoid the `{%` combination, you probably could not avoid all the others.

To answer your last question:

According to chapter 8 of The TeXbook, `{` at the end of a line where the next line is non-empty behaves like `{` followed by a space followed by the content of the next line minus leading spaces. So

```tex
\setkomavar{firsthead}{
  \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}{
```

is equivalent to

```tex
\setkomavar{firsthead}{ \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}{
```

and perhaps the space before `\usekomafont` causes a warning.

But if the next line is empty, instead of an extra space there will be an extra `\par` (paragraph end), so

```tex
\setkomavar{firsthead}{
  \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}{
```

is equivalent to

```tex
\setkomavar{firsthead}{\par\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}{
```

And the final `%` suppresses the extra character, so

```tex
\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \usekomafont{pageheadfoot}{
```

is equivalent to

```tex
\setkomavar{firsthead}{\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}{
```

Answer (score 1):

In TeX, during tokenization(!!!), you can access characters via `^^`-notation as well.
I.e.,

- instead of `%` you can write `^^e` or `^^25`.
- instead of `{` you can write `^^;` or `^^7b`.
- instead of `}` you can write write `^^=` or `^^7d`.

The pattern is

`^^⟨character whose code-point-number +/- 64 yields the code-point-number of the character to denote⟩`

*(Subtraction is done if the code-point-number of the character is in range 64..127. Addition is done if the code-point-number of the character is in range 0..63.)*

or

`^^⟨lowercase-hexadecimal-representation of the number of the code-point of the character to denote⟩`.

So in the .tex-file instead of `{%` you can write `{^^e` or `{^^25` or `^^;%` or `^^;^^e` or `^^;^^25` or `^^7b%` or `^^7b^^e` or `^^7b^^25`.

However in verbatim-mode, i.e., with things like `\verb|..|` or `\begin{verbatim}...\end{verbatim}` `^^`-notation is turned off.

The term "code-point-number"/"number of the code-point" refers to the number which the corresponding character has in TeX's internal character encoding scheme which with traditional TeX-engines is ASCII and with XeTeX-/LuaTeX-based TeX-engines is unicode (whereof ASCII is a strict subset).

---

Ad *"This means that I cannot have any {% combination in my tex template."*

Are you sure about this?

[Jinja Template Designer Documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/) says in section "Escaping":

> The easiest way to output a literal variable delimiter (`{{`) is by
> using a variable expression: `{{ '{{' }}`

Section "Expressions/Literals" says:

> Everything between two double or single quotes is a string.

Does `{{ '{%' }}` not work out for you?

Comment: I just redefined the expression `{{` to `{+` and the statement `{%` to `{~` in inja. I think it works best!